# Grails 2.0: Issue testing flash.message

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller, grails-2.0

I have a unit test for my `UserController` but since upgrading to Grails 2.0, the `flash` variable always seems to return an emtpy map with no message.

Here are some code snippets of the `UserControllerTests`:

```
@TestFor(UserController)
@Mock(User)
class UserControllerTests {
...
  void testSaveSucceeds() {
  params.userName = 'Joe'
  ...
  controller.save()
  assert null != flash.message
  assert '/user/list' == response.redirectedUrl
  }
}
```

In `UserController`:

```
def save = {
  def userInstance = new User(params)
  if (userInstance.validate()) {
    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [userInstance.userName ])
    ...
}
```

But my test result is as follows:

```
assert null != flash.message
            |  |     |
            |  [:]   null
            false
```

I have tried as an integration test as well because otherwise the `response` was null as weill but it did not fix the flash issue. The same problem also exists with `view` and `model`.

What am I missing? Any help highly appreciated.

Regards

Jonas

**EDIT:**

Here's a weird scenario:

My controller has the following:

```
def test = {
   flash.message = "Message"
}

def save = {
   flash.message = "Message"
}
```

My Test looks like that:

```
void testSaveSucceeds() {
   controller.save()
   println ">>> ${flash}"
   controller.test()
   println ">>> ${flash}"
}
```

The output like that:

```
>>> [:]
>>> [message:Message]
```

Interesting to mention is also that the debugger in IntelliJ stops at a breakpoint in the test() action but not in save()

HOW can that be????

Regards

Jonas

Comment: did it work using grails 1.3.7?

Answer (score 1):

For me it means that `userInstance.validate()` return `false` ie the validation failed.

Comment: That's not the reason, the validation does not fail. And even if I assign a message to `flash.message` in the else block, I get have the same problem.